# How to print a character using Shell script

Tags: bash, append, config

Below is my script that acquire the MAC of the machine and store within a config file.

My problem is that within each line have the character " " and it dont print it inside the file, how can I write the file using " "

```
MAC=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')
echo "
view.sslVerificationMode = *3*
view.autoConnectDesktop = *TRUE*
view.autoConnectBroker = *TRUE*
view.kioskLogin = *TRUE*
view.nonInteractive = *TRUE*
view.fullScreen = *TRUE*
view.nomenubar = *TRUE*
view.defaultBroker = *viewcs*
view.defaultUser = *CM-${MAC//:/_}*
" > /etc/vmware/view-mandatory-config;
sed -i 's/*/"/g' /etc/vmware/view-mandatory-config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `cat` and a [here-doc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) you can use multi-line input without escaping charaters

```
MAC=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')
cat << EOT > /etc/vmware/view-mandatory-config
view.sslVerificationMode = "3"
view.autoConnectDesktop = "TRUE"
view.autoConnectBroker = "TRUE"
view.kioskLogin = "TRUE"
view.nonInteractive = "TRUE"
view.fullScreen = "TRUE"
view.nomenubar = "TRUE"
view.defaultBroker = "viewcs"
view.defaultUser = "CM-${MAC//:/_}"
EOT
```

**`cat`** will relay the stdin input generated by the [**here document**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to stdout, thus enabling redirection to a file

Comment: The crux of your answer is not `cat`, but use of a **here doc** (search for `Here Documents` in `man bash`). Also, to help the OP, please replace the `*` instances with `"` to demonstrate that your approach works.

Comment: thanks for the info, didn't fully read the sed command, so I missed that he was replacing `*`s

Comment: Happy to help; if you add info about here documents to your answer (`cat` is just the auxiliary tool that relays the stdin input generated by the here document to stdout, thus enabling redirection to a file), I'm happy to up-vote.

Comment: It worked very well, thanks for show me the Here document, I will take a deep look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape double-quotes within the outer double-quotes by putting a backslash in front of them:

```
MAC=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')
echo "
view.sslVerificationMode = \"3\"
view.autoConnectDesktop = \"TRUE\"
view.autoConnectBroker = \"TRUE\"
view.kioskLogin = \"TRUE\"
view.nonInteractive = \"TRUE\"
view.fullScreen = \"TRUE\"
view.nomenubar = \"TRUE\"
view.defaultBroker = \"viewcs\"
view.defaultUser = \"CM-${MAC//:/_}\"
" > /etc/vmware/view-mandatory-config
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, it worked too, this will help me a lot of times.